# How to show similar data on two y-axis in c3 chart

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am using c3 charts and I want to show two y-axis in the chart. C3 charts allows two y-axis with two different sets of data. see example [here](http://c3js.org/samples/axes_y2.html).
My problem is that I want to show data of first y-axis on the second y-axis but not to attach any data with second axis.
How can I do that, I couldn't find any solution on web.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went through the docs carefully and found a solution,

```
  axis: {
    y2: {
      show:true,
      default: [0,400],
      tick: {
        count: 5,
        values:[0,100,200,300]
      }
    }
  }
```

found more exact solution for this

```
chart.data.axes({'data1':'y2'})
```